# Event Receiver to add value in field automatically in sharepoint list

Tags: event-receivers

I have a list having 5 fields. I want to add value in 5th column when i add new item. Like when i fill value for 4 columns and save item, then 5th column should auto populate with value = "Checked". Thanks

Comment: You might also look into a workflow as a no-code solution. Unless there's more to the requirements than you're showing right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public virtual void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
       properties.ListItem["Status"] = True;
       properties.ListItem.Update();
    }
```

Try this code

Comment: shouldn't it be `properties.ListItem` ?

Answer (score 4):

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    SPListItem oItem = properties.ListItem;
    oItem["Status"] = true;
    oItem.Update();
}
```

referenced: Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms437502(v=office.14).aspx)